# Build & deploy the functionapp but not finding any deployments in deployment center

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

using the below task to build & deploy fucntion app

```
      - task: AzureFunctionApp@2
        displayName: 'Deploy Azure Function'
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
          appType: 'functionAppLinux'
          appName: fucntionapp
          deploymentMethod: zipDeploy
```

Even when using the above YAML i dont see anything is deployed to the deployment center

Earlier i have used to deploy the funtionapp it is working fine but when i am deploying now getting this output

Got service connection details for Azure App Service:'functionapp'

The Deployment Type option does not apply for Linux Consumption.

Updating App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"https://rg1bfc5.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package

Updated App Service Application settings.

Updated WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Application setting to https://rg1bfc5.blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package

Syncing triggers for function app

Any pointers?

Comment: have you tried using AzureFunctionApp task with version 1 and removing `deploymentMethod: zipDeploy` from the task? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce "The Deployment Type option does not apply for Linux Consumption" when using your yaml configuration. To resolve it, use `AzureFunctionApp@1` task and remove `deploymentMethod: zipDeploy` from the task.

```
          - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
              appType: functionAppLinux
              appName: $(functionAppName)
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

`deploymentMethod` is required when `appType != functionAppLinux && appType != "" && package NotEndsWith .war && Package NotEndsWith .jar`